# NodeJS Selenium-webdriver custom wait method not returning desired result

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, mocha.js

I am trying to write a set of automated tests in Mocha to test a node web application.

I made a custom wait method in order to get the webdriver to wait until an input box or text area contains the sent text from then sendKeys() method before moving forward with checking.

I am having trouble getting a custom wait method to actually return the value I want.

```
    function waitForAttributeValue(element, attribute, value)
    {
       return element.getAttribute(attribute).then(result => 
       {
          if(result === value)
             return result;
          else
             return false;
       });
    }
```

And then I place inside a wait like such:

```
let result = this.driver.wait(waitForAttributeValue(element, 'value', 'hello'), 4000);
```

Result will sometimes return the value I'm expecting ('hello' in this case) and sometimes it will return false which causes my test to fail.

Based on the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html)

> To define a custom condition, simply call WebDriver.wait with a
>   function that will eventually return a truthy-value (neither null,
>   undefined, false, 0, or the empty string)

Is there something I'm missing or did I misinterpret the documentation?

Additionally I'm using:
Node v.8.11.3 and Selenium node package v.4.0.0-alpha.1

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.wait()` expect a function as argument, but you passed-in a promise.

You should change the function `waitForAttributeValue` to return a function as following:

```
function waitForAttributeValue(element, attribute, value) {
    return function () {
        return element.getAttribute(attribute).then(result => {
            if (result === value)
                // return result; recommend to return true as here
                // because empty string will be treated as False
                return true;
            else
                return false;

            // or you cam simply return result === value to avoid
            // using  if/else.
            return result === value;

        });
    };
}
```